# German family name on a piece of leather

Tags: handwriting

Is anyone able to read this handwriting? It is most likely a German family name which is written on a piece of leather. I am thinking it says "könig _ _ _ _" but my handwriting interpretation skills more limited than my German.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would say "König" too.

Comment: Thanks Luca00711, but the word appears to continue beyond the letter "g"

Comment: What can you tell about the piece of leather? What is its intended purpose?

Comment: The pictured leather is: the inside of a 1933 pistolen tasche

Comment: could be "Könige ff" where ff is a military abbreviation

Comment: you could try to use some photo-software to play with the contrast and RGB-colors to maybe make it more readable. I maybe see an "Könige", because there is definitely something behind the "g". And it seems, that there was written something above the first f of the (possible) "ff", what looks like a "4"

Comment: Added another picture maybe better. Not sure what photo software - any suggestions?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for our plattform. Neither will it help people with similar questions, nor does it need expertise in German language. It's not even obviously german language. A last name can be nearly every combination of letters. We will not be able to decide, which answer might be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no full answer, I think it's not possible to answer this because a name can be pretty much anything.

First letter is clearly a "K", and it's worth noting that the bold horizontal stroke above might belong to the K in its Kurrent or Sütterlin form.

The second letter is unclear. "ö" as in "König" would need two Umlaut-dots above. You could argue that the horizontal stroke from above belongs to the ö, and maybe that's true, but a horizontal dash wouldn't be the normal way to mark Umlauts in Sütterlin. The letter itself looks more like an "a" to me, so it could be "a" or "ä", too.

Then there's some space where just some pale ink is visible. An "n" would be possible, but also m, w and maybe others.

"ig" is pretty clear.

Then another pale letter, maybe an "s", could also be "e" or others.

Then a big scribble that isn't pale at all, but undecipherible, seems to have been overwritten, or maybe it's some kind of symbol. If I had to interpret it as letters, I'd probably go for "ff", but I'm not sure at all. The stain in the lower part doesn't help either.

It's not even clear if that's the end of the word. There seems to be some pale ink after that, too, but nothing I can identify as letters at all.

So to me it seems like we won't find out exactly what this holster was marked with.